# Using mathpazo with scrlttr2 not globally changing font

Tags: scrlttr2, mathpazo

I would like to use mathpazo with scrlttr2.

If I load the package the backaddress over the recipients address is not set in palatino.

How can I change the font for all the text? Many thanks in advance!

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{From Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{From Street\\00000 From City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 0000 0\,00\,00\,00}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(From Name)}
\setkomavar{place}{From City}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To Name\\To Street\\00000 To Place}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
    \opening{Ladies and Gentlemen,}

    \blindtext

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: change `[osf,sc]{mathpazo}` to `{tgpagella}`

Comment: @yo' That does not work for me ... backaddress is still sans serif.

Comment: Without testing, i would suggest something like `\addtokomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily}` EDIT: And testing confirms, that it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Page 176 of the Koma-Script manual tells you that the default font for the back address is `\sffamily`. Just add

```
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\normalfont}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{From Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{From Street\\00000 From City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 0000 0\,00\,00\,00}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(From Name)}
\setkomavar{place}{From City}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\setkomafont{backaddress}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To Name\\To Street\\00000 To Place}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
    \opening{Ladies and Gentlemen,}

    \blindtext

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]