# Multiple recipients using tabular in letter class

Tags: tables, letters

When I try to use tabular to accommodate multiple addressees using the letter class, the pdf renders, but I get the error:

```
line 32: Argument of \@no@pgbk has an extra }. \end{letter}
line 32: Paragraph ended before \@no@pgbk was complete. \end{letter}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,  11pt]{letter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\def \fromaddress{\null}   



\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
            {addressname\newline{}line1\newline{}line2} &
            {addressname2\newline{}line1\newline{}line2} 
        \end{tabular}}

%   \begin{letter}{recip1\\address1\\address2}  %<==== This line works
    \opening{Dear my addressees:}



    \lipsum[1]


\vspace{12pt}

\closing{Yours faithfully,\\
        \fromsig{THISISME\\}
        \fromname{ME\\Title1\\title2}
     }


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Note that when I comment out the begin{letter} lines that use the tabular, and pop the vanilla line that's commented, all works.

Any insight at to what's going on and whether I can fix it?

UPDATE:

```
\documentclass[firsthead=no,pagenumber=topleft, headsepline=yes, 11pt,paper=letter,foldmarks=no,refline=nodate,enlargefirstpage=no,parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrlttr2} %refline=nodate
% stolen from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302281/using-mathpazo-with-scrlttr2-not-globally-changing-font

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}


%\ihead{Recipient }



\setkomavar{signature}{This is me\\Lord High Muckety Muck}

\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }
\setkomavar{location}{\par\raggedleft{\usekomavar{date}}}

\LetterOptionNeedsPapersize{letter}{letter}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\normalfont}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} 



\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrindent}{10pt }  %indent the To Address a little bit
\@setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin } %make date in location area align to text
\@addtoplength{lochpos}{1in}
\@setplength{locvpos}{2in}
\@setplength{locheight}{.5in}
\@setplength{toaddrheight}{3.75in }
\@setplength{refaftervskip}{0in }
\@setplength{refvpos}{5in }  % This will move the message body UP or DOWN
\@setplength{subjectbeforevskip}{0pt}
\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{0pt}
%\@addtoplength{subjectvpos}{-20pt}
\@setplength{sigindent}{3in}  %indent of signature

\makeatother


\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\renewcommand{\pagemark}{{Recipient, page \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}  %%Change recipient name here



\begin{document}
%       \ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{letterhead.pdf}
  \begin{letter}{\begin{tabularx}{5in}{XX}

a&b  % <======  This works

%       a&b \\
%       c&d           <+++++++++ Two row tabular doesn't work

\end{tabularx}}



 %   \setkomavar{subject}{Subject}fDIV=
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} 
\opening{Respected marmots,}

\blindtext

{\begin{tabularx}{5in}{XX}

        a&b \\
        c&d


\end{tabularx}}

\Blindtext





    \closing{Sincerely}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I tried the scrlttr2 option described below.  It worked wonderfully with a 1-row tabularx for the address, but it crashed and burned for a two-row (which you can see by commenting the one-row table and uncommenting the two-row).  This gives a (first) error msg of

*Argument of \TX@get@body has an extra }. \opening{Respected marmots,}*, followed by a whole mess more.

Comment: ... not if you replace `\\` by `\cr`, see my updated answer before. BTW, I needed to comment out the babel package, but there might be something wrong with my TeX installation (which I updated just today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something non-boilerplate, which the [`letter` class](//ctan.org/pkg/letter) is not built for, mostly because it makes some assumptions about the content you'll supply. Specifically, the (first) argument of the `letter` is *processed* in order to *extract* information, like the addressee's name and address. As soon as you start doing something else there, you could run into problem.

A possible solution is to build a letter from scratch - it's straight-forward:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{
  margin=1in % or whatever suits you
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}% Remove page headers/footers

\mbox{}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l @{}}
  Address \\
  of \\
  Sender \\ \\
  \today
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % Vertical skip between sender/receiver address

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l}
  Name and \\
  Address \\
  of \\
  Receiver 1
\end{tabular} \quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l}
  Name and \\
  Address \\
  of \\
  Receiver 2
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % Vertical skip between receive address and letter opening

Dear adressees,

\medskip % Vertical skip between letter opening and letter body

\lipsum[1]

\medskip % Vertical skip between letter body and closing

%\hspace*{.5\linewidth}% ...for a middle-left-aligned closing
Yours faithfully,

\medskip % Vertical skip between letter closing and signature start

\vspace{5\baselineskip} % Content that includes your signature, or space for it

My signature

\bigskip % Vertical skip between signature and attachment references

cc: % people this letter is cc-ed to

\medskip

encl: % list of anything enclosed

\medskip

ps: % any post scriptums

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a workaround.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,  11pt]{letter}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{{\makebox[5cm][l]{marmot1}}\makebox[5cm][l]{marmot2}\\
\makebox[5cm][l]{address1}\makebox[5cm][l]{address2}\\
\makebox[5cm][l]{mountain1}\makebox[5cm][l]{mountain2}
}

 \opening{Dear my addressees:}


    \lipsum[1]


\vspace{12pt}

\closing{Yours faithfully,\\
        \fromsig{THISISME\\}
        \fromname{ME\\Title1\\title2}
     }


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT/UPDATE** If you are open to a different document class, you may try

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
% stolen from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302281/using-mathpazo-with-scrlttr2-not-globally-changing-font
\usepackage{blindtext}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{From Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{From Street\\00000 From City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 0000 0\,00\,00\,00}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(From Name)}
\setkomavar{place}{From City}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\setkomafont{backaddress}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  Murmeltier\newline Saas Fee\newline Switzerland & 
  Marmot\newline Vancouver Island\newline  Canada
\end{tabular}}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
    \opening{Respected marmots,}

    \blindtext

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

OK, another round. I find that `tabularx` also works if one uses `\cr` (which is deprecated, right;-) instead of `\\`.

```
\documentclass[firsthead=no,pagenumber=topleft, headsepline=yes, 11pt,paper=letter,foldmarks=no,refline=nodate,enlargefirstpage=no,parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrlttr2} %refline=nodate
% stolen from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302281/using-mathpazo-with-scrlttr2-not-globally-changing-font

%\usepackage[english]{babel} % I had to comment this out.

%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}


%\ihead{Recipient }



\setkomavar{signature}{This is me\\Lord High Muckety Muck}

\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }
\setkomavar{location}{\par\raggedleft{\usekomavar{date}}}

\LetterOptionNeedsPapersize{letter}{letter}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\normalfont}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} 



\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrindent}{10pt }  %indent the To Address a little bit
\@setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin } %make date in location area align to text
\@addtoplength{lochpos}{1in}
\@setplength{locvpos}{2in}
\@setplength{locheight}{.5in}
\@setplength{toaddrheight}{3.75in }
\@setplength{refaftervskip}{0in }
\@setplength{refvpos}{5in }  % This will move the message body UP or DOWN
\@setplength{subjectbeforevskip}{0pt}
\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{0pt}
%\@addtoplength{subjectvpos}{-20pt}
\@setplength{sigindent}{3in}  %indent of signature

\makeatother


\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\renewcommand{\pagemark}{{Recipient, page \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}  %%Change recipient name here



\begin{document}
%       \ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{letterhead.pdf}
  \begin{letter}{\begin{tabularx}{5in}{XX}
       a & b\cr
       c & d       %    <+++++++++ Two row tabular doesn't work
\end{tabularx}}


 %   \setkomavar{subject}{Subject}fDIV=
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} 
\opening{Respected marmots,}

\blindtext



{\begin{tabularx}{5in}{XX}

        a&b \\
        c&d


\end{tabularx}}

\Blindtext





    \closing{Sincerely}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a workaround, but having to shuffle the lines of each address together is a chore.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I agree, but it is not too different in effort from separating the entries by `\newline` commands. It is (probably) not too different from writing a macro that does the reshuffling, but I am suspecting that there must be a better solution.

Comment: The update is particularly interesting.  I hadn't ever considered using KOMA scripts, but this is certainly worth a look.  Already figured out how to move the date above the addresses.

Comment: The scrlttr2 works really well for a one-row tabularx, but when I tried to add rows to the tabular, it crashed and burned

Comment: There are two tables in there in one tabularx.  It runs the way it is, but if you comment out the one-row entry and uncomment the two-row, it crashes.  I haven't tried it as a tabular.  I suppose that's next.